# Draw a dash-dotted line

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I produce a dash-dotted line `.-.-.-.-`? I tried to find something in the `tikz` manual, but didn't find anything.

Comment: please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38423/want-to-fill-line-with-repeating-string  and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253291/equivalent-leaders-construction

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The various pre-defined dash patterns are documented in section *15.3.2 Graphic Parameters: Dash Pattern* of the manual (for version 3.0.1.a dated 29 August 2015). They are `dotted`, `dashed`, `dash dot` and `dash dot dot`. Each of these have denser and looser variants, e.g. `densely dashed` and `loosely dotted`. Equivalently for the others.

In addition you can specify a custom pattern using e.g. `dash pattern={on 4pt off 1pt on 2pt off 3pt}`, which I guess is self explanatory.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick,dash dot] (0,1) -- (5,1);
\draw [thick,dash pattern={on 7pt off 2pt on 1pt off 3pt}] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Addendum

If you want to put a line like this in the text, and aligned better to the surrounding text, then you can add the `baseline=<length>` option to the `tikzpicture`. By default the bottom end of the `tikzpicture` is placed on the baseline of the surrounding text. If you add `baseline=10pt` then the `tikzpicture` will be placed so that y=10pt in its internal coordinate system is on the baseline of the surrounding text.

Here is an example. `\tikz` is a short form of the `tikzpicture` environment, intended for simple pictures placed in the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \tikz\draw [thick,dash dot] (0,0) -- (3,0); dolor sit amet

Lorem ipsum \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\draw [thick,dash dot] (0,0) -- (3,0); dolor sit amet
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` seem to be coordinates. Is it right, that the coordinate with the lower x part is set to be wherever the environment ends? My tests tell so. Than how can I set the line in the middle line high, like appearing like this: `before --- after`

Comment: *wherever the environment starts

Comment: @Ben I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I think you're after the `baseline` key, see the addition to my answer.

Comment: I am sorry, but how can it be written if the length is needed to be a fraction of textwidth or 2cm for example?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou As mentioned above, the default unit vectors are 1cm, so a line from (0,0) to (2,0) would be 2cm. That said, you can also use explicit units, so `\draw (0,0) -- (2cm,0);` works. And TeX lengths work as well, so you can say e.g. `\draw (0,0) -- (0.1\linewidth,0);`

Answer (score 10):

Here is a version using leaders.  While all the parameters can be changed, the main ones are `\dashdotline{<length>}` to draw the line, with these configurations: `\dashfrac{<percent of repetition used by dash>}`; `\replength=<repetition-length>\relax`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\newlength\replength
\newcommand\repfrac{.40}% PERCENT OF REPETITION USED BY DASH
\newcommand\dashfrac[1]{\renewcommand\repfrac{#1}}% MACRO TO ALTER \repfrac
\setlength\replength{8.5pt}% REPITITION LENGTH
\newcommand\rulewidth{.6pt}% DASH WIDTH
\def\dashht{.5\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\dp\strutbox\relax}
\newcommand\tdashfill[1][\repfrac]{\cleaders\hbox to \replength{%
  \smash{\rule[\dashht]{\repfrac\replength}{\rulewidth}%
  \kern.5\dimexpr\replength-\repfrac\replength-2.5pt\relax%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\dashht-.3pt}{.}}}\hfill}
\newcommand\dashdotline[1]{%
  \makebox[#1][l]{\tdashfill\hfil}}
\begin{document}
x\dashdotline{2in}y\par
\replength 17.5pt
x\dashdotline{1in}y\par
\dashfrac{.66}
x\dashdotline{1in}y
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution with leaders, not perfect but as simple as possible:

```
\xleaders\hbox to 1em{$- \cdot$}\hfill $-$
```

If you will use this often, define some macro as `\dashdotted`, 
If you want a specific length instead of filling the line, simply enclose it in a `\makebox` (e.g.,`\makebox[2cm]{\dashdotted}`). MWE:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twocolumn]{article}
\def\dashdotted{\xleaders\hbox to 1em{$- \cdot$}\hfill $-$}
\begin{document}
x\dashdotted 1\par 
x\makebox[2cm]{\dashdotted}1\par
xxxxx\dashdotted 1\par 
xxxxxxxxxx\dashdotted 1\par 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\dashdotted 1
\end{document}
```