# Creating a rectangle area plot with pgfplots/tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I found this plot/image online. I need to change the values of the boxes a bit and I want to plot it in a better quality with PGFPlots.

[image]

This is the code of my attempt:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[

    title={Title},
    xlabel={Voltage [V]},
    ylabel={Temperature [°C]},
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=-15, ymax=300,
    xtick={0,2,4,6,8,10},
    ytick={0,50,100,150,200,250,300},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]
\fill [red](axis cs:0,-15) rectangle (axis cs:2.5,300);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Problems that came up:

1. Scaling of the axis
2. Label of the areas (rectangles)
3. Grid inside the plot

Is there a way to get this three points solved within PGFPlots?

Comment: the colors are of criminal intent for colorblinds.

Comment: area 1 can be green and the rest red. The original plot is not mine

Comment: 1) What exactly do you mean here? 2) `\node [white] at (axis cs:x,y) {txt};`? 3) Do you mean drawing the dashed and dotted lines? If yes, first part of http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327983/586, combined with `axis cs`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. 1) to lable the axis like in the given picture. if possible even with the borders of the operating window.

Comment: Check documentation for keywords width, height, scale only axis, and axis on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you mean something similar to ... (The rest should not be a too big problem. But since you are a bit unspecific, I don't want to guess here.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use `compat' level 1.11 or higher so coordinates don't have to be
        % prefixed with `axis cs:' (any more)
        compat=1.11,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        region/.style={
            draw=black!50,
            dashed,
        },
        Node/.style={
            midway,
            red,
        },
        declare function={
            xmin=0;
            xmax=10.5;
            ymin=-50;
            ymax=300;
        },
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={Voltage in V},
            ylabel={Temperature in ${}^\circ$C},
            xmin=xmin,
            xmax=xmax,
            ymin=ymin,
            ymax=ymax,
            axis background/.style={
                fill=red!10,
            },
            extra x ticks={3},
            extra y ticks={60},
        ]
            \draw [region,fill=green!20] (3,0) rectangle (4.2,60)
                node [midway,green] {1};

            \draw [region]
                (xmin,ymin) rectangle (2.5,ymax)  node [Node] {2}
                (4.5,ymin)  rectangle (6.5,60)    node [Node] {3a}
                (2,ymin)    rectangle (4.5,-2)    node [Node] {3b}
                (2.5,60)    rectangle (6.5,130)   node [Node] {4}
                (6.5,ymin)  rectangle (xmax,130)  node [Node] {5}
                (2.5,130)   rectangle (xmax,210)  node [Node] {6}
                (2.5,210)   rectangle (xmax,ymax) node [Node] {7}
            ;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: First of all you solved all the points. One question, when I plot the code I get -50, 0, 50, 60, 100, 150, 200, 250, and 300 on the y-axis. So how can edit the lable on the axis to go in 100 steps?

Comment: If you have PGFPlots v1.13 or higher adding `ytick distance=100` to the `semilogxaxis` environment options should to that.