# Putting 2 dotted lines inside a rhombus

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd, bullets

I know how to draw 3 rhombi above each other as follows:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
    \begin{document}
    \[\begin{tikzcd}[sep = 2em,
        /tikz/rhombus/.style={shape=diamond,draw,minimum size=2em}]
     |[rhombus,draw,minimum size=3em]|{}\arrow[r,shorten >=0.5em,shorten <=0.5em] & 
     |[rhombus,append after command={\pgfextra{\let\myln\tikzlastnode}
     (\myln.north) node[anchor=south,rhombus] {}
     (\myln.south) node[anchor=north,rhombus] {}}]|{}\\
    \end{tikzcd}\]
    \end{document}
```

But what if inside the big rhombus I want to put 2 dotted lines to indicate the places where I will pinch it to get the 3 rhombi?

Any help in drawing this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2GRD.png?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `execute at end picture` to add additional TikZ code to the diagram. So if you give the big node alias with `alias=foo` added to the style of the node, you can draw lines between the anchors of the node.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}[sep = 2em,
    /tikz/rhombus/.style={shape=diamond,draw,minimum size=2em},
    execute at end picture={
      \draw [densely dotted] (foo.north west) -- (foo.north east);
      \draw [densely dotted] (foo.south west) -- (foo.south east);
    }
    ]
 |[rhombus,draw,minimum size=3em, alias=foo]|{}\arrow[r,shorten >=0.5em,shorten <=0.5em] & 
 |[rhombus,append after command={\pgfextra{\let\myln\tikzlastnode}
 (\myln.north) node[anchor=south,rhombus] {}
 (\myln.south) node[anchor=north,rhombus] {}}]|{}\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I need them 2 dashed lines instead?

Comment: @Happy `densely dashed` instead of `densely dotted`, you mean?

Comment: @Happy You can also specify the pattern manually, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327982/draw-a-dash-dotted-line/327983#327983