# Help with styling arrows to nodes, adding legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have used my very basic knowledge of `tikz` to make the image on the LHS (or top, depending on device viewer), whereas what I actually want in the image on the RHS (created with mathematica):

[image]
[image]

This is the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto,
node distance=2cm, scale=1, 
transform shape, align=center, 
state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2cm}],

\tikzset{arrowhead=2cm}

\node[state]  (GS) {Person};  
\node[state,  right=of GS]  (G1) {work};
\node[state, above right=of GS] (G2) {family};
\node[state, above left=of GS] (G3) {friends};
\node[state, left=of GS] (G4) {partner \\wife};
\node[state, below left=of GS] (G5) {community};
\node[state, below right=of GS] (G6) {local \\agencies};

\path[->] (GS) edge node {} (G1)
          (GS) edge node {} (G2)
          (GS) edge node {} (G3)
          (GS) edge node {} (G4)
          (GS) edge node {} (G5)
          (GS) edge node {} (G6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have tried but failed to legend and style the arrow lines to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all note that your code gives the error `I do not know the key '/tikz/arrowhead', to which you passed '2cm', and I am going to ignore it.` There is no such key to adjust the size of arrow tips, which I assume is what you were trying to do(?).

To actually modify the tip sizes, load  the `arrows.meta` library instead of the old and deprecated `arrows` library. `arrows.meta` define a set of new tips including `Stealth` (note capital S), which can take various settings. For example, you can use

```
>={Stealth[width=7pt, length=8pt]}
```

to get a bigger tip. Note that the braces (`{}`) are necessary to hide the `]` from the parsers, otherwise that closing bracket will be seen as the closing bracket for `\begin{tikzpicture}[...]`

To make a dashed line, use `dashed`, e.g. [Draw a dash-dotted line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327982/draw-a-dash-dotted-line/327983#327983)

For the legend draw a line, and add a node to the right of the end point, i.e. something like `\draw (a,b) -- +(1.5,0) node[right] {foo};` for some useful choice of the coordinate `(a,b)`. The `+` before `(1.5,0)` means that it is a relative coordinate. In the code below I placed it relative to the community node.

I also remove the empty nodes at each `edge`, because if you're not labeling the edges those nodes are just not needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  automata,
  arrows.meta, % instead of the deprecated arrows
  calc,
  positioning
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 >={Stealth[width=7pt, length=8pt]},
 shorten >=1pt, auto,
 node distance=2cm, scale=1, 
 transform shape, align=center, 
 state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2cm}
]

\node[state]  (GS) {Person};  
\node[state,  right=of GS]  (G1) {work};
\node[state, above right=of GS] (G2) {family};
\node[state, above left=of GS] (G3) {friends};
\node[state, left=of GS] (G4) {partner \\wife};
\node[state, below left=of GS] (G5) {community};
\node[state, below right=of GS] (G6) {local \\agencies};

\path[->] (GS) edge (G1)
          (GS) edge[dashed] (G2)
          (GS) edge[dashed] (G3)
          (GS) edge[dashed] (G4)
          (GS) edge[dashed] (G5)
          (GS) edge[dashed] (G6);


\draw (G5.south west) ++(-1.5,-1.5) coordinate (tmp) -- +(1.5,0) node[right] {Relationship};
\draw [dashed] (tmp)  ++(0,-0.5) -- +(1.5,0) node[right] {Relationship needed};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: many thanks! If I wanted 5 nodes, could I specify degrees/radians? ie instead of `(G5.south west)` and `below left`?

Comment: @martin For the legend position you could use e.g. `(G5.200) ++(-1,5, -1..5)` if you want to. If you're talking about the general layout of the diagram, you can use polar coordinates, e.g `\node[state] (G2) at (72:3cm) {family};`. That assumes that `GS` is positioned at `(0,0)` (which it is in this case), otherwise you could do e.g. `\path (GS.center) ++(72:3cm) node[state] (G2) {family};`.  Haven't tested any of that code by the way.

Comment: thank you, will try it out

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,calc,positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto,
node distance=2cm, scale=1, 
transform shape, align=center, 
state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2cm}],

\node[state]  (GS) {Person};  
\node[state,  right=of GS]  (G1) {work};
\node[state, above right=of GS] (G2) {family};
\node[state, above left=of GS] (G3) {friends};
\node[state, left=of GS] (G4) {partner \\wife};
\node[state, below left=of GS] (G5) {community};
\node[state, below right=of GS] (G6) {local \\agencies};

\path[-{Stealth[length=5mm]},dashed] (GS) edge node {} (G1)
          (GS) edge node {} (G2)
          (GS) edge node {} (G3)
          (GS) edge node {} (G4)
          (GS) edge node {} (G5);
          
\path[-{Stealth[length=5mm]},solid] (GS) edge node {} (G6);
\draw ([yshift=-2cm] current bounding box.south west) -- ++(2cm,0) node[xshift=1.2cm]{Relationship};
\draw[dashed] ([yshift=-1cm] current bounding box.south west) -- ++(2cm,0) node[xshift=1.8cm]{Relationship needed};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With new contraintes. I've never been a big fan of `positionning'

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto,  align=center, 
state/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=2cm}],

\node[state]  (GS) {Person};  
\node[state] at  (canvas polar cs:angle=90,radius=4cm) (G1) {work};
\node[state] at  (canvas polar cs:angle=18,radius=4cm) (G2) {family};
\node[state] at  (canvas polar cs:angle=162,radius=4cm) (G3) {friends};
\node[state] at  (canvas polar cs:angle=234,radius=4cm) (G5) {community};
\node[state] at  (canvas polar cs:angle=-54,radius=4cm) (G6) {local \\agencies};

\path[-{Stealth[length=5mm]},dashed] (GS) edge node {} (G1)
          (GS) edge node {} (G2)
          (GS) edge node {} (G3)
          (GS) edge node {} (G5);
          
\path[-{Stealth[length=5mm]},solid] (GS) edge node {} (G6);
\draw ([yshift=-2cm] current bounding box.south west) -- ++(2cm,0) node[right]{Relationship};
\draw[dashed] ([yshift=-1cm] current bounding box.south west) -- ++(2cm,0) node[right]{Relationship needed};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: We can do better for the legend because there I positioned the labels by hand

Comment: thank you! If I wanted 5 nodes, could I specify degrees/radians? ie instead of `current bounding box.south west` and `below left`?

Comment: What do you mean by "5 nodes"?

Comment: as opposed to the six used here. In other words, if (eg) community was removed

Comment: eg as per this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iucs9.png)

Comment: Nothing to do with `current bounding box.south west` but you can move the legend up by modifying `[yshift=-2cm`

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Five satellite nodes, using polar coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
         C/.style = {circle, draw, semithick,
                     text width=4em, align=center,
                     inner sep=2pt, outer sep=2pt},
every edge/.style = {draw, -{Stealth[angle=60:5pt 6]}, semithick} % <---
                    ]
\node[C] (GS) {Person};
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {work, family, friends, partner wife, local agencies}
{
    \node[C] (s\j) at (\j*360/5:33mm) {\i};    % five satellite nodes
}
\path   (GS) edge[dashed] (s1)
             edge[dashed] (s2)
             edge[dashed] (s3)
             edge[dashed] (s4)
             edge         (s5);
% legend
\draw           (GS) ++ (-4,-4.0) -- ++ (1,0) node[right] {Relationship};
\draw[dashed]   (GS) ++ (-4,-4.5) -- ++ (1,0) node[right] {Relationship needed};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

More about arrows style you can find in Ti*k*Z & PGFF manual for version 3.1.9a, chapter 16.5 Reference: Arrow Tips, on page 211. Used arrows style is described on page 212 and 215 (for Straight Barb).

[image]

**Addendum**
In cases, when you like to rotate image for some angle, just add this angle to calculation of anchors. For example:

```
\node[C] (s\j) at (<angle offset> +\j*360/5:33mm) {\i};
```

This ` is in the case when you like to have node "work" at 90 degree is:

```
    \node[C] (s\j) at (90-360/5+\j*360/5:33mm) {\i};    % five satellite nodes with angle offset (90-360/5) =18 degree
```

Considering this in above MWE, it will produce the following image:

[image]

Comment: thank you. What would the syntax for `(\j*360/5:33+360/10:33mm)` be (ie, if I wanted to rotate it by 360/10)?

Comment: Ah, found it: `(360/20+\j*360/5:33mm)`

Comment: @martin, syntax in your first comment is correct. See addendum to answer.