# Creating quantized (repeating) patterns with TikZ to fill whitespace in lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to ask the community if the following is possible in principle, and how I would go about it in general. I am learning a little bit of `tikz` (for tcolorbox, mostly), but wanted to know whats the best approach before I sink hours into this and realize I could have done it much easier.

First a simple picture, maybe this is enough:
[image]

I want to have a repeating pattern (simple pictish keypattern as example) quantized to the remaining whitespace in a line, for example. I figured this should be possible with `tabto` or some other package which can give me the remaining whitespace (here by subtracting the \CurrentLineWidth from \textwidth, maybe?). This package, i figured, should be able to position the (tikz)picture at the margin of the page, too.

- Is there a way to detect the start and end of the picture, to insert fitting tiles (esp since the widths of the pictures vary)?
- Is it more practical to do this by inserting prerendered repeating units?
- Is this a suitable problem for `tikz`? I think so since I am convinced that letting one program control every step of this process, highly dependent on isometry, should yield the best results, but things like the varying width give me pause.

I dont expect a coded answer since this is obviously a complicated problem, but would appreciate if you could tell me whether this is realizable, and how you would go about that. Point me to some packages and drop me some keywords, I hope I can figure this out this way.

Comment: The (La)TeX primitive to fill up space is `\leaders`; you can explore them [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leaders?tab=Votes](here). I never tried to mix them with Ti*k*Z...

Comment: Probably https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253303/38080 can help...

Comment: With `remember picture` it is possible to figure out much space is to the right of a TikZ picture before the end of the line. How do you want to approach this when the remaing space is not an integer factor of the tile size? With `\leaders`, you could place the left and right end and then let TeX fill the remaining space with the main tile.